# How to use LINQ or Lambda instead of nested and multiple foreach statements

Tags: c#, linq, loops, lambda

How can I use LINQ or Lambda instead of nested and multiple foreach statements.

I want to use a better syntax than nested foreach statements to overwrite the initial list with items from the second list.

In the code below:

- I want to overwrite initialList with those in secondList that have the same Value. (Remove Red)
- Use the items in secondList where Value was the same (Yellow)
  New initialList list should include (Green and Yellow)

  ```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      int useProd = 2;
      int useDomain = 0;

      var person1 = new Person() { prodId = 1, Value = "foo", domainId = 0, Name = "Red" };
      var person2 = new Person() { prodId = 1, Value = "bar", domainId = 0, Name = "Green" };
      var person3 = new Person() { prodId = 1, Value = "foo", domainId = 1, Name = "Yellow" };

      var initialList = new List<Person>();
      initialList.Add(person1);
      initialList.Add(person2);

      var secondList = new List<Person>();
      secondList.Add(person3);

      List<Person> personsToRemove = new List<Person>();
      List<Person> personsToUpdate = new List<Person>();

      foreach (var pers1 in initialList)
      {
          foreach (var pers2 in secondList)
          {
              if (pers1.Value == pers2.Value)
              {
                  personsToRemove.Add(pers1);
                  personsToUpdate.Add(pers2);
              }
          }
      }
      foreach (var remPers in personsToRemove)
      {
          initialList.Remove(remPers);
      }
      foreach (var updPers in personsToUpdate)
      {
          initialList.Add(updPers);
      }
      foreach (var item in initialList)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Value: {0}, prodId: {1}, domainId: {2}, Name: {3}", item.Value, item.prodId, item.domainId, item.Name));
      }

      Console.ReadKey();
  }
  public class Person
  {
      public int prodId { get; set; }
      public string Value { get; set; }
      public int domainId { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
  }
  ```

Comment: I'm almost sure that this question should be in [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of stackoverflow

Comment: The code doesn't show any attempt to solve the problem, it just creates two lists.  Have you tried anything? Did you encounter a problem? Did you check the set-oriented methods Enumerable.Union, Enumerable.Except etc?

Comment: @Patrick As this seems to be sample code it **isn't** a good fit for code review. It will be closed as **off topic**

Comment: @Heslacher Oh I thought solved it with foreachs and was trying to change it to linq but since it does not show the foreachs you should be probably right

Comment: @Niike2 If you post on codereview you can just post the original foreach with as much context as possible and ask how this could be changed to linq/lambda and we would be happy to help you.

Comment: Also it doesn't help to paste the code to a `main()` method if nobody can test it without the `Person` class.

Comment: @Heshlacher I can do that! Just a question, I should not ask here how to union two lists with linq/lambda and how to compare/filter the lists on two properties? Should I have skipped the code to explain the concept? Added Person class, sorry!

Comment: Sorry, I am not the typical SO user ( at least I don't ask ). You would need to check the [help] for how to ask properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested loops are most efficiently represented with a `join`. In addition, it would be helpful efficiency-wise to not have to do a linear-search on the entire list just to remove an element and then to add a new one in. There is an overload of `Enumerable.Select()` we can use to embed the item index in the result, so that the element can simply be replaced directly.

Putting it all together, it looks like this:

```
var join = from p1 in initialList.Select((p, i) => new { Person = p, Index = i })
           join p2 in secondList on p1.Person.Value equals p2.Value
           select new { Index = p1.Index, Replacement = p2 };

foreach (var item in join.ToList())
{
    initialList[item.Index] = item.Replacement;
}
```

The above code replaces the original code starting with the declarations of the `personsToRemove` and `personsToUpdate` lists, and the first three `foreach` loops (i.e. all but the one that displays the final result).

Notes:

- From the `initialList`, the code synthesizes an anonymous type containing the `Person` instance and the index of that instance in the list.
- The `join` clause pairs up all of the items from each list where the `Value` properties are equal.

**Important:** if there are multiple elements in either list with the same `Value` property, they are each paired with every other element in the other list having that same `Value`. I.e. if `initialList` has two elements having the `Value` of "foo" and `secondList` has three such elements, you will wind up with *six* elements in the resulting join. Your question does not define whether this is possible, nor what you would want to happen if it were, so I've just ignored that possibility here. :)

- The `join` result is projected to a new anonymous type containing the index of the element to be replaced, and the new value.
- The query result is materialized by calling `ToList()`. This is necessary because the join is otherwise deferred and modifying the `initialList` would invalidate the query.
- Of course, in the remaining `foreach` all that the code then needs to do is assign to the appropriate index position in the list the replacement value determined by the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Generics as well. Below is the short code will work for you:

```
    initialList.ForEach(p =>
    {
        if (secondList.Any(sp => sp.Value == p.Value))
        {
            initialList.Remove(p);
            initialList.Add(secondList.Single(spu => spu.Value == p.Value));
        };
    });
```